# How to remove space from xml tag using XStream?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have the xml below that has a number value

```
<detalhe>
  <numLinha>1048  </numLinha>
</detalhe
```

the tag numLinha will be converted to a number attibute in java, however i receive the folow message because there are spaces at the end of tag:

```
Exception in thread "main"  
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: For input string "1048                    "

@XStreamAlias("detalhe")
public class BodyDetail implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -1000785985130865301L;

   @XStreamAlias("numLinha")
   private Integer lineNumber;
}
```

Comment: do you have to use xstream? a plain xml parser would do the job just fine...

Comment: i don't know this approach. i'll search, but i think should be a way to remove space of xml, maybe with converters. @vtd-xml-author 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with a custom converter of Integer Type.

1. First i created the converter:

   ```
   package converter;

   import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter;
   import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
   import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
   import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
   import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;

   public class IntegerConverter implements Converter {

      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      @Override
      public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
          return clazz.equals(Integer.class);
      }

      @Override
      public void marshal(Object object, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
           MarshallingContext context) {
      }

      @Override
      public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
           UnmarshallingContext context) {
         String text = (String)reader.getValue();
         Integer number = Integer.parseInt(text.trim());
         return number;
      }    
   }
   ```
2. I registered the converter:

   ```
    public class XMLRead {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

         XStream xStream = new XStream();    
         xStream.registerConverter(new IntegerConverter());
      }
    }
   ```